# Simple Search & Matrix. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: matrix, simple-search

I have read every post I can find on this topic and cannot get it to work.

I have set **both** the Matrix field and Matrix columns to Searchable.
I have **re-saved** my entries.

No matter what, my search results will not pull up an entry with a text string match in the Label/Text column of my matrix field.

**Search Page:**

```
{exp:search:simple_form result_page="/search_results" search_in"everywhere" where="any"}
                <p>
                    <label for="keywords">Search:</label>
                    <br>
                    <input type="text" name="keywords" id="keywords" value="" size="18" maxlength="100">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="submit" value="submit" class="submit">
                </p>
                {/exp:search:simple_form}
```

**Results Page:**

```
{exp:search:search_results backspace="7"}
                <p><a href="{auto_path}/result"><strong>{title}</strong></a><br />
                    {excerpt}</p>
                <span style="float:right;">Site Section: <a href="/{channel_short_name}">{channel}</a></span>
                <ul class="image">
                    <li class="arrow"><a href="{auto_path}/result">Read More...</a></li>
                </ul>
                <hr/>
                {/exp:search:search_results}
```

EE v2.3.1
Matrix 2.2.3.2

Any ideas?

**Sorry everyone, I cannot believe I left out "="
search_in"everywhere"
All good now. What a waste of a day.
/sigh.**

Comment: Can you add your solution as an answer and mark it as so?